# Link to HTMl file in another folder and update URL

Tags: javascript, java, html, angular

In my controller, I have an array of strings that define folder names from which I want to grab index.html from (assume all folders have an index.html):

```
$scope.folderNames = ['DCB', etc]
```

I want to have a link on my HTML page for each of these files; when one is clicked, the URL should be updated in this pattern:

```
baseURL/folderNames/ --> baseURL/folderNames/DCB
```

and in this case, DCB's index.html should show up.

Currently, I am doing:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="folder in folderNames">
        <td>
            <!-- Not sure what to put here to load HTML file from another folder -->
        </td>
</table>
```

I was previously using ui-sref and passing in folderName from the ng-repeat to go to a different state, updating the URL like so:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('folderNames', {
        url: '/BASEURL/folderNames',
        templateUrl: 'PATH_TO_FOLDER_NAMES_HTML/view.html
    })
    .state('folderNames.view' {
        url: /:folder,
        templateUrl: 'PATH_TO_FOLDER/index.html
    });
```

But now when I click on a folderName from the folders page, the webapp appends PATH_TO_FOLDER from folderNames.view's templateUrl to the URL, which isn't what I want. I'm thinking that I shouldn't be using ui-sref because rather than a transition in state, I just want to show an HTML file from another folder in my project directory.

How would I go about updating the URL to include the folderName that I just clicked on, and then displaying the index.html from that folderName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use interpolation in `ng-href`something like:

```
<a ng-href="{{baseURL +'/' + folderNames +'/' + folder}}">{{folder}}</a>
```

This assumes you have variables in scope like

```
$scope.baseURL = '/appDirectory';
$scope.folderNames = 'images';
```

Answer (score 0):

just had to put

```
 <a href="path/index.html"></a>
```

sigh.